# Unable to adjust image and text in a div come at the same point

Tags: html, css

Hi Am trying to keep a image and text in a div side by side with background color green am able to keep but the image is not at the right place so when am trying to match it with the text am unable to do it

Here is the code u can run code and see

```
<div style="background-color:#4CAF50;display:inline-table;height:20px;margin-top:60px;padding:5px;border-radius:100px;margin-right:10px;">
        <a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;"><img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/12c0e780d9.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;" alt="tag"><span style="margin-left:8px;font-weight:bold">Get The Code</span></a>
    </div>
```

The jsfiddle link is here
https://jsfiddle.net/cmbaf2p3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<div style="background-color:#4CAF50;display:inline-table;height:20px;margin-top:60px;padding:5px;border-radius:100px;margin-right:10px;">
        <a href="www.google.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;"><img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/12c0e780d9.png" style="width:20px;height:20px; vertical-align:middle" alt="tag"><span style="margin-left:8px;font-weight:bold">Get The Code</span></a>
    </div>
```

I have just added 
vertical-align: middle to 'img'

Answer (score 1):

You can simply apply, `vertical-align: middle` on both, your image and your text.

```html
<div style="background-color:#4CAF50;display:inline-table;height:20px;margin-top:60px;padding:5px;border-radius:100px;margin-right:10px;">
  <a href="www.happycheckout.in" style="text-decoration:none;color:white; vertical-align: middle;">
    <img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/12c0e780d9.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;vertical-align: middle;" alt="tag"><span style="margin-left:8px;font-weight:bold">Get The Code</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add float:left in your img tag,

```
<img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/12c0e780d9.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;float:left" alt="tag"><span style="margin-left:8px;font-weight:bold">Get The Code</span></a>
```